# PhoneGap External Browser Issue

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I've been learning how to use PhoneGap the last few days and I'm facing an issue that only happens when I run in Android. When I run it in PhoneGap's Developer app using "phonegap serve" it works absolutely fine.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function(){

    // Handle link clicks in our own way
    $(document).find('a').on('click', bind_a_rel_external);

});

function bind_a_rel_external(e){

    if($(this).attr('rel') == 'external'){

        e.preventDefault();

        window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_system');

    }

}
```

**HTML** (Note the rel="external")

```
<a href="https://facebook.com/motostats" rel="external">Like us on Facebook<br><br>
<img src="assets/img/facebook.png" width="50"></a>
```

Just to reiterate; works fine in PhoneGap's developer app. Doesn't work in native Android. And the inappbrowser plugin has been initilized. So I'm assuming it's not compiling properly. I'm not building this app for iOS yet so cannot test it in that.

Thanks in advance. I've been pulling my hair out over this all weekend.

Answer (score 0):

In your config.xml there is a line saying something like this:

```
<access origin="127.0.0.1" />
```

Try changing this to

```
<access origin="*" />
```

and let me know if it works!

Comment: This was already set in the config.xml - Was the first thing I checked ;).